# How to manage a Exception - UserControl.ascx does not exist - After Migration

Tags: web-part, migration, user-controls

I have got a problem with exception UserControl.ascx does not exist on context. It making me after migration from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013. How to solve this problem, please help:

[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the path to include reference from 15 hive i.e `private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/`